# Plus and Minus Keys don't work

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, hardware

I dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10. In my Ubuntu, the plus and minus signs of my laptop keyboard don't work. They work fine from the numpad, however not from the keys at the top of the keyboard. Nothing is printed when I press those keys. However, '=' and '_', which are on the same keys work fine.

What can I do about this issue?

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

but this didn't make any difference.

I have checked my keyboard layout, it is correct.

After typing

```
xev
```

in the terminal, and pressing the minus sign key, the following is the output in the terminal:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  88  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

No KeyPress and KeyRelease events occur. And I did not even touch the mouse yet this is the output it shows. There is definitely no hardware issue since the keys work fine in Windows.

This is what appears when I press '=':

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x6aa, subw 0x0, time 1811459, (213,28), root:(376,187),
    state 0x0, keycode 21 (keysym 0x3d, equal), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3d) "="
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3d) "="
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x6aa, subw 0x0, time 1811530, (213,28), root:(376,187),
    state 0x0, keycode 21 (keysym 0x3d, equal), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3d) "="
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: obviously your keys are mapped to a different event, which means that their keysym code is different. Happened to me with a locked "FN" key on a Thinkpad.

Comment: @kanehekili could you please help me rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem.
this is how i solved it:
i indeed had made a custom shortcut to zoom in and zoom out for shift _ and shift + and as soon as i removed the shortcuts, BOOM it WORKED!

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? The answer is a little ambiguous 